# Itemize in beamer makes my text appear outside the slide

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize

I begun LaTeX one week ago and I am no professionnal yet. I am confronted with beginner's problems but there is one I really can't fix and I already asked colleagues/google but I can't find any answer.

I am writing a presentation with beamer and I want to make an enumeration. The problem is that my text appears outside the slide and seems right-aligned, as shown in this picture:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Physiological functions of H2S}\vspace{5pt}
Roles of H2S:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2cm,labelsep=*]
\setlength{\leftmargini}{5pt}
\item[Angiogenesis]
\item[Cytoprotection]
\item[Anti-oxydant]
\item[Anti-inflammatory]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also tried with the enumeration but it doesn't change anything.

It would be really great if someone could help me. Sorry for the newbie question!

Have a great day.

Comment: Don't use `enumitem` with beamer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `enumitem` with beamer, they are incompatible. From the look of it you could instead use a `description` environment. If this isn't the layout you are trying to achieve, look into beamer's `mini templates` to adjust the itemization.

Unrelated to the problem:

- you don't need `graphicx`, beamer already loads it
- using the `float` package in a documentclass without floating mechanism does not make much sense
- Instead of `multicol` I would use beamers own columns mechanism
- If your beamer version is reasonable up to date, you don't need `etoolbox`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Physiological functions of H2S}\vspace{5pt}
Roles of H2S:
\begin{description}%[leftmargin=2cm,labelsep=*]
\setlength{\leftmargini}{5pt}
\item[Angiogenesis]
\item[Cytoprotection]
\item[Anti-oxydant]
\item[Anti-inflammatory]
\end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, description works like magic!

Comment: @mjen Not magic, just beamer :)